# Big Cartel - Lunch Break Theme

Tags: html, css, bigcartel

I want to make my logo slightly bigger but I cannot seem to work it out. Could anyone guide me if I wanted to double the current size? Here is the current coding:

```
<img alt="{{ store.name }} Home" class="store-image" src="{{ theme.images.header_logo.url | constrain: '', 140 }}" srcset="{{ theme.images.header_logo.url | constrain: '', 280 }} 2x, {{ theme.images.header_logo.url | constrain: '', 140 }} 1x">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style it as you see it fit. This is just a proof-of-concept and is probably very far from the actual sizes that you desire:

```
<img alt="{{ store.name }} Home" class="store-image" src="{{ theme.images.header_logo.url | constrain: '', 140 }}" srcset="{{ theme.images.header_logo.url | constrain: '', 280 }} 2x, {{ theme.images.header_logo.url | constrain: '', 140 }} 1x" style="width: 2000px; height: 2000px">
```